¿Por qué el programa crashea luego de cargar los datos de un archivo binario?
Me aparece este error en la consola al ejecutar el programa:
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
El programa crea bien el archivo binario, pero al cerrar el compilador y ejecutarlo de nuevo, debería abrir el archivo con los datos que ya se almacenaron anteriormente. Aquí adjunto un fragmento del código.
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
//creacion del registro//

struct Estudiante {
    long CI= 0;
    char Nombre[25]=" ";
    int Edad = 0;
    string Grado = " ";
    char Sexo = ' ';
    bool Discapacidad;
    char Seccion = ' ';
    float Prom = 0;
    bool Activo;
    string Fecha_I = " ";
};

/*Función para cargar datos desde el archivo*/

vector<Estudiante> cargarEstudiantes() {
    vector<Estudiante> estudiantes;

    ifstream archivo("INSCRIPCIONES.dat",ios::binary); /* aca lo puse ifstream para ver si se arreglaba , originalmente estaba en fstream , ios::binary|ios::in*/

    if (archivo.is_open()) {
        Estudiante est;
        while(archivo.read((char*)&est, sizeof(Estudiante))) {
            estudiantes.push_back(est);
        }
        archivo.close();
    }else if(archivo.fail()) {
        cout<<" No se pudo abrir el archivo\n\n";
        cout<<"Presione----------> [ENTER] <----------para continuar......\n";
        cin.get();
        system("cls");
    }

    return estudiantes;

}

/*Función para guardar datos en el archivo*/

void guardarEstudiantes(const vector<Estudiante>& estudiantes) {
    ofstream archivo("INSCRIPCIONES.dat" , ios::app); /*aca lo mismo originalmente estaba 
                                                  en fstream, ios::binary|ios::app*/

    if(!archivo) {
        cout <<" No se Pudo abrir El archivo para La Escritura de los Estudiantes...\n";
        return;
    }
    for (const auto& est : estudiantes) {
        archivo.write((char*)&est, sizeof(Estudiante));

    }
    archivo.close();
}


Detente un momento a pensar cómo estás guardando tu estructura de datos:
archivo.write((char*)&est, sizeof(Estudiante))

Es la forma más simple de guardar información en binario pero debes saber bien lo que haces.
Es posible que la información no se guarde tal cual en su estructura interna. Además, todos los punteros que puedan existir dentro de la estructura interna solo son válidos durante la ejecución del programa.
La clase string seguramente guarde un puntero a la información que quieres. Al cargar los estudiantes de nuevo: el puntero ahora apunta a una dirección de memoria que muy probablemente no sea válida y la cadena como tal no fue cargada ya que ni siquiera fue guardada.
Guardar la estructura directamente en binario no es seguro cuando está compuesta por punteros o estructuras que no conoces.
La solución más simple es que en lugar de string utilices un arreglo:
struct Estudiante {
    long CI= 0;
    char Nombre[25]=" ";
    int Edad = 0;
    char Grado[25] = " ";
    char Sexo = ' ';
    bool Discapacidad;
    char Seccion = ' ';
    float Prom = 0;
    bool Activo;
    char Fecha_I[25] = " ";
};

Si aún quieres usar un string, puedes almacenar un campo a la vez y darle un tratamiento especial a las clases problemáticas. Por ejemplo:
Estudiante est;
archivo.write((char*)&est.CI, sizeof(est.CI));
archivo.write((char*)&est.Nombre, sizeof(est.Nombre));
...

archivo.write(est.Grado.c_str(), est.Grado.length());
...

La lectura sería similar aunque un poco más complicada a la hora de recuperar los string:
Estudiante est;
archivo.read((char*)&est.CI, sizeof(est.CI));
...

char c;
while (c = archivo.get())
    est.Grado += c;

...

Pero lo más seguro es guardar la información en formato de texto. Los más populares son CSV y JSON así que podrás encontrar librerías.

es cierto , tienes razón , gracias amigo en vd , crees que seria conveniente cambiar la extension del archivo a txt? , lo tengo en .dat igual sirve

@eliud en Windows se utiliza para identificar de qué formato tiene su contenido aunque en Linux las extensiones no son tan relevantes
